# Allocates memory from the unmanaged memory of the process by using the specified number of bytes

Tags: c#, c++

is there a function or something in C++ allows me to Allocate memory from the unmanaged memory of the process by using the specified number of bytes.

like in c# for exmapl:

```
_key = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(key.P.Length * sizeof(UInt32) + key.S.Length * sizeof(UInt32));
```

Comment: are you sure you dont want to use malloc or mmap? i'm not sure what you mean by unmanaged memory...

Comment: Sorry, I had to -1 this.  This could have been resolved by learning the language you are working in, or, failing that, a simple web search.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ (without CLI), all memory is unmanaged.

```
 void * MyMem  = new byte[MySize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using the `new` operator should cause the C++ libraries to allocate the memory from the unmanaged memory of the process. If you really really want to use just a number of bytes, you would need to use `malloc` and then cast the pointer, but if that's what you want to do, you should consider just using plain C. Otherwise, if you need to use C++, I would recommend the `new` operator and have it figure out the proper number of bytes:

```
//Allocate the memory
uint32_t *_key = new uint32_t[key.P.Length + key.S.Length];

//Do what you need with it

//Cleanup and deallocate the memory
delete[] _key;
```

Or in C:

```
//Allocate
uint32_t *_key = malloc(key.P.Length * sizeof(UInt32) + key.S.Length * sizeof(UInt32));

//Use

//Cleanup
free(_key);
```